# More efficient way of writing this friends of friends sql query

Tags: mysql

I have written this query which returns a users friends and the friends on those friends. As there is a lot of sub queries going on here I thought there much be a more efficient way of writing it, but it's a bit beyond me.

users table

```
++++++++++++++++++
+ user_id + name +
++++++++++++++++++
+ 1       + bill +
+ 2       + bob  +
+ 3       + sam  +
+ 4       + ben  +
++++++++++++++++++
```

user_friendships table

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ sender_user_id + receiver_user_id +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1              + 2                +
+ 2              + 3                +
+ 4              + 2                +
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

The table is bi-directional so user 1 is a friend of user 2 and user 2 is a friend of user 1.

User 1 only has 1 friend user 2. User 2 has 2 friends, user 3 and user 4.

When the below query is run for user 1, user 2, 3 and 4 are returned.

query

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE ( user_id IN 

(SELECT receiver_user_id as user_id 
FROM user_friendships 
WHERE sender_user_id IN

(SELECT receiver_user_id as user_id 
FROM user_friendships 
WHERE sender_user_id = '1' 
UNION 
SELECT sender_user_id as user_id 
FROM user_friendships 
WHERE receiver_user_id = '1')

UNION

SELECT sender_user_id as user_id 
FROM user_friendships 
WHERE receiver_user_id IN

(SELECT receiver_user_id as user_id 
FROM user_friendships 
WHERE sender_user_id = '1' 
UNION 
SELECT sender_user_id as user_id 
FROM user_friendships 
WHERE receiver_user_id = '1')

)

OR user_id IN

(SELECT receiver_user_id as user_id 
FROM user_friendships 
WHERE sender_user_id = '1' 
UNION 
SELECT sender_user_id as user_id 
FROM user_friendships 
WHERE receiver_user_id = '1')
)
AND user_id != '1'
```

To clarify the end result of the friends and friends of friends query should be a single list of user_ids so that it can be joined with the user's table to retrieve the name etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be helpfull: It tries to traverse the tables as few times as possible.

```
-- First generation: Friends
SELECT
  IF(firstgen.sender_user_id=<your-user-id>,firstgen.receiver_user_id,firstgen.sender_user_id) AS friend
FROM
  user_friendships AS firstgen
WHERE
  firstgen.receiver_user_id=<your-user-id>
  OR firstgen.sender_user_id=<your-user-id>

UNION

-- Second generation: Friends of friends
SELECT
  IF(secondgen.sender_user_id in(firstgen.sender_user_id,firstgen.receiver_user_id),secondgen.receiver_user_id,secondgen.sender_user_id) AS friend
FROM
  user_friendships AS firstgen
  INNER JOIN user_friendships AS secondgen ON
    (firstgen.sender_user_id=<your-user-id> AND (secondgen.sender_user_id=firstgen.receiver_user_id OR secondgen.receiver_user_id=firstgen.receiver_user_id))
  OR
    (firstgen.receiver_user_id=<your-user-id> AND (secondgen.sender_user_id=firstgen.sender_user_id OR secondgen.receiver_user_id=firstgen.sender_user_id))
WHERE
  firstgen.receiver_user_id=<your-user-id>
  OR firstgen.sender_user_id=<your-user-id>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. this looks much more like what i'm looking for, however I'm receiving a syntax error for line 2, assuming it is something to do with the if statement and mysql? obviously i've replaced your-user-id with a user id.

Comment: There was a dot instead of a comma in Line 2 (and corresponding line later on) Sorry, happens to me all the time.

Comment: you're right, thanks. if i use the user id 1 it only returns user id 2. It should also return 3 and 4 as they are friends of 2. not sure what part of the second gen isn't correct

Comment: OK, third time is a charme: Fixed thinko in IF() in second query, now it works with your data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query that brings everything

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM
(SELECT sender_user_id,receiver_user_id FROM user_friendships) A
UNION
(SELECT receiver_user_id,sender_user_id FROM user_friendships)) B
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uf1.sender_user_id,uf2.receiver_user_id
FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
ON uf1.receiver_user_id = uf2.sender_user_id) C
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uf1.receiver_user_id,uf2.sender_user_id
FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
ON uf1.sender_user_id = uf2.receiver_user_id) D;
```

Note that

- Subqueries A and B are 1st generation bidirectional
- Subqueries C and D are 2nd generation bidirectional

Here is your sample data:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS friends;
CREATE DATABASE friends;
USE friends
CREATE TABLE users
(id int not null auto_increment,
name varchar(10),primary key (id));
insert into users (name) values
('bill'),('bob'),('sam'),('ben');
CREATE TABLE user_friendships
(sender_user_id int not null,
receiver_user_id int not null,
primary key (sender_user_id,receiver_user_id),
unique key (receiver_user_id,sender_user_id));
insert into user_friendships values
(1,2),(2,3),(2,4);
```

Here is your sample data loaded

```
mysql> DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS friends;
(id int not null auto_increment,
name varchar(10),primary key (id));
insert into users (name) values
('bill'),('bob'),('sam'),('ben');
CREATE TABLE user_friendships
(sender_user_id int not null,
receiver_user_id int not null,
primary key (sender_user_id,receiver_user_id),
unique key (receiver_user_id,sender_user_id));
insert into user_friendships values
(1,2),(2,3),(2,4);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> CREATE DATABASE friends;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> USE friends
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE users
    -> (id int not null auto_increment,
    -> name varchar(10),primary key (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.08 sec)

mysql> insert into users (name) values
    -> ('bill'),('bob'),('sam'),('ben');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> CREATE TABLE user_friendships
    -> (sender_user_id int not null,
    -> receiver_user_id int not null,
    -> primary key (sender_user_id,receiver_user_id),
    -> unique key (receiver_user_id,sender_user_id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert into user_friendships values
    -> (1,2),(2,3),(2,4);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.06 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from users;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | bill |
|  2 | bob  |
|  3 | sam  |
|  4 | ben  |
+----+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from user_friendships;
+----------------+------------------+
| sender_user_id | receiver_user_id |
+----------------+------------------+
|              1 |                2 |
|              2 |                3 |
|              2 |                4 |
+----------------+------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Here is the run of the 'everything query'

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT sender_user_id,receiver_user_id FROM user_friendships) A
    -> UNION
    -> (SELECT receiver_user_id,sender_user_id FROM user_friendships)) B
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT uf1.sender_user_id,uf2.receiver_user_id
    -> FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
    -> ON uf1.receiver_user_id = uf2.sender_user_id) C
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT uf1.receiver_user_id,uf2.sender_user_id
    -> FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
    -> ON uf1.sender_user_id = uf2.receiver_user_id) D;
+----------------+------------------+
| sender_user_id | receiver_user_id |
+----------------+------------------+
|              1 |                2 |
|              2 |                3 |
|              2 |                4 |
|              2 |                1 |
|              3 |                2 |
|              4 |                2 |
|              1 |                3 |
|              1 |                4 |
|              3 |                1 |
|              4 |                1 |
+----------------+------------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Now to see just relationships for user 1 , just use this query

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM
(SELECT sender_user_id,receiver_user_id FROM user_friendships) A
UNION
(SELECT receiver_user_id,sender_user_id FROM user_friendships)) B
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uf1.sender_user_id,uf2.receiver_user_id
FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
ON uf1.receiver_user_id = uf2.sender_user_id) C
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uf1.receiver_user_id,uf2.sender_user_id
FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
ON uf1.sender_user_id = uf2.receiver_user_id) D) everything
WHERE (sender_user_id=1 and receiver_user_id<>1)
or (sender_user_id<>1 and receiver_user_id=1);
```

Here is that output

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM (
    -> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT sender_user_id,receiver_user_id FROM user_friendships) A
    -> UNION
    -> (SELECT receiver_user_id,sender_user_id FROM user_friendships)) B
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT uf1.sender_user_id,uf2.receiver_user_id
    -> FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
    -> ON uf1.receiver_user_id = uf2.sender_user_id) C
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT uf1.receiver_user_id,uf2.sender_user_id
    -> FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
    -> ON uf1.sender_user_id = uf2.receiver_user_id) D) everything
    -> WHERE (sender_user_id=1 and receiver_user_id<>1)
    -> or (sender_user_id<>1 and receiver_user_id=1);
+----------------+------------------+
| sender_user_id | receiver_user_id |
+----------------+------------------+
|              1 |                2 |
|              2 |                1 |
|              1 |                3 |
|              1 |                4 |
|              3 |                1 |
|              4 |                1 |
+----------------+------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Now hook up the names frmo the user table like this:

```
SELECT u1.name,u2.name FROM (
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM
(SELECT sender_user_id,receiver_user_id FROM user_friendships) A
UNION
(SELECT receiver_user_id,sender_user_id FROM user_friendships)) B
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uf1.sender_user_id,uf2.receiver_user_id
FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
ON uf1.receiver_user_id = uf2.sender_user_id) C
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uf1.receiver_user_id,uf2.sender_user_id
FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
ON uf1.sender_user_id = uf2.receiver_user_id) D) everything
INNER JOIN users u1 ON everything.sender_user_id = u1.id
INNER JOIN users u2 ON everything.receiver_user_id = u2.id
WHERE (sender_user_id=1 and receiver_user_id<>1)
or (sender_user_id<>1 and receiver_user_id=1);
```

Here is that output

```
mysql> SELECT u1.name,u2.name FROM (
    -> SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT sender_user_id,receiver_user_id FROM user_friendships) A
    -> UNION
    -> (SELECT receiver_user_id,sender_user_id FROM user_friendships)) B
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT uf1.sender_user_id,uf2.receiver_user_id
    -> FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
    -> ON uf1.receiver_user_id = uf2.sender_user_id) C
    -> UNION
    -> SELECT * FROM
    -> (SELECT uf1.receiver_user_id,uf2.sender_user_id
    -> FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
    -> ON uf1.sender_user_id = uf2.receiver_user_id) D) everything
    -> INNER JOIN users u1 ON everything.sender_user_id = u1.id
    -> INNER JOIN users u2 ON everything.receiver_user_id = u2.id
    -> WHERE (sender_user_id=1 and receiver_user_id<>1)
    -> or (sender_user_id<>1 and receiver_user_id=1);
+------+------+
| name | name |
+------+------+
| bob  | bill |
| sam  | bill |
| ben  | bill |
| bill | bob  |
| bill | sam  |
| bill | ben  |
+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT

Hook up the names using LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN preserves the order the numbers were returned

```
SELECT u1.name,u2.name FROM (
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM
(SELECT sender_user_id,receiver_user_id FROM user_friendships) A
UNION
(SELECT receiver_user_id,sender_user_id FROM user_friendships)) B
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uf1.sender_user_id,uf2.receiver_user_id
FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
ON uf1.receiver_user_id = uf2.sender_user_id) C
UNION
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT uf1.receiver_user_id,uf2.sender_user_id
FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
ON uf1.sender_user_id = uf2.receiver_user_id) D) everything
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON everything.sender_user_id = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON everything.receiver_user_id = u2.id
WHERE (sender_user_id=1 and receiver_user_id<>1)
or (sender_user_id<>1 and receiver_user_id=1);
```

Here is that output

```
mysql>     SELECT u1.name,u2.name FROM (
    ->     SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM
    ->     (SELECT sender_user_id,receiver_user_id FROM user_friendships) A
    ->     UNION
    ->     (SELECT receiver_user_id,sender_user_id FROM user_friendships)) B
    ->     UNION
    ->     SELECT * FROM
    ->     (SELECT uf1.sender_user_id,uf2.receiver_user_id
    ->     FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
    ->     ON uf1.receiver_user_id = uf2.sender_user_id) C
    ->     UNION
    ->     SELECT * FROM
    ->     (SELECT uf1.receiver_user_id,uf2.sender_user_id
    ->     FROM user_friendships uf1 INNER JOIN user_friendships uf2
    ->     ON uf1.sender_user_id = uf2.receiver_user_id) D) everything
    ->     LEFT JOIN users u1 ON everything.sender_user_id = u1.id
    ->     LEFT JOIN users u2 ON everything.receiver_user_id = u2.id
    ->     WHERE (sender_user_id=1 and receiver_user_id<>1)
    ->     or (sender_user_id<>1 and receiver_user_id=1);
+------+------+
| name | name |
+------+------+
| bill | bob  |
| bob  | bill |
| bill | sam  |
| bill | ben  |
| sam  | bill |
| ben  | bill |
+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. Your solution is good, however my original concern was that my overall query was made up of 9 statements so I was looking to optimise it. I think this query would be slower still?

Comment: I guess a refactoring with number 1 inside all the subqueries would make it faster

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't get you the names, just the matching IDs:

```
user_friendships
UNION
SELECT UF1.sender_user_id AS sender_user_id, 
      UF2.receiver_user_id AS receiver_user_id
FROM user_friendships as UF1, 
     user_friendships as UF2
WHERE UF1.receiver_user_id = UF2.sender_user_id 
   AND UF1.sender_user_id != UF2.receiver_user_id;
```

That is: user_friendships gives you the friends, and the SELECT gives you the friends-of-friends (making sure we don't count somebody as their own friend).

Comment: thanks for your reply, not quite what i'm looking for though you'll see compared to the posts above

Comment: If we add "UF1.sender_user_id=1 AND" after the WHERE clause, in what way would this NOT produce what you originally asked for?  (To get the single column your revision requested, simply remove the UF1 item from the SELECT section.)

Comment: Thank you for the update. With the original data this technically works with your revision, however the relationships are by directional. By only searching for sender_user_id=1 we are ignoring any friendships that we initiated by the other person, i.e. receiver_user_id = 1. I've changed the data in the friendships table to reflect such a scenario, and in that case, only users 2 and 3 are returned.